# modal should slide from top

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

Implemented a modal of twitter boots trap....
It works fine when I don't put it in my site.....
After I included it in my site the modal shows up but does not slide from the top....

Actual modal

http://jsfiddle.net/nJ6Mw/1/

modal not sliding from top

http://jsfiddle.net/y88WX/12/embedded/result/

```
<div id="example" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: block;" aria-hidden="false">
                <div class="modal-header"> <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>

                     <h3>This is a Modal Heading</h3>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                     <h4>Text in a modal</h4>

                    <p>You can add some text here.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Call to action</a>
 <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I don't see where "options" is being set in http://jsfiddle.net/nJ6Mw/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y88WX/12/embedded/result/ i am talking with respect to this fiddle

Comment: I guess my point is that you've set up the working one in a way where we can't see what options are set, so it's not surprising that yours is not working.

Comment: A null options object would just revert the modal code to defaults .. What's puzzling is multiple includes of jquery.js in the page where this isn't working. You must skim down the example where it's not working.

Comment: and please add bootstrap-transitions.js in your own page just like you added an external resource in the example that's working.

Comment: @uchamp: thanks for your reply i included that too but still not working http://jsfiddle.net/y88WX/15/embedded/result/

Comment: your html is still not clean or so it seems. There are multiple head and body tags. Multiple includes of the same files like jquery.min.js, jquery.js, jquery-1.6.2.js, jquery.cslider.js and lots of other such resources. Please clean up your files and then share a fresh fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you have it within your #container div instead of outside of it in the body??
Hard to tell cause you're second fiddle doesnt compile right